# Does Angular Sepherd support routing?

Tags: angular

I want to use Angular Sepherd https://github.com/shipshapecode/angular-shepherd to create a feature tour in my application. The tour navigates to different pages but no where in the documention of this library I can see the routing option. Can someone please help with an example for this case if it supports.

I went through the documentation. Nothing there about routing.

Comment: The routing is in Angular, not in Shepherd. It's unclear what you are trying to do. Angular-Shepherd is just a wrapper to use Shepherd in Angular.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What I mean is Let's say that my routing for the application is as below: 

{ path: 'new', component: NewCompComponent }, 
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/patient-details', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
{ path: 'patient-details', component: PatientDetailsComponent } ]; 

 I want the first highlight for tour in /patiend-details and then on click of next, it should navigate to /new page and highlight the button present in that page. How to achieve this ? Basically I want to create a multi-page tour.